Problema con Moodle 4.1 - Error dmlreadexception
Buenas tardes!
Espero puedan ayudarme con un problema que vengo teniendo desde hace unos días. 
Instalé Moodle 4.1 desde el Autoinstalador de Hostinger y no una, sino dos veces a la hora de agregar alumnos al curso en un punto de la matriculación me aparece el siguiente error: dmlreadexception
Le pregunté a Soporte en Hostinger si podía asistirme ya que era su instalador y me enviaron acá.
A continuación les envío el error completo.
Ojalá puedan ayudarme, no sé qué más hacer.
SELECT id, sid, state, userid, lastip, timecreated, timemodified FROM qa2p_sessions WHERE sid = ?
[array (
  0 => 'lihoocr4fmmgom7uogkkguhm9t',
)]
Error code: dmlreadexception
* line 494 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: dml_read_exception thrown
* line 293 of /lib/dml/moodle_read_slave_trait.php: call to moodle_database->query_end()
* line 1398 of /lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php: call to mysqli_native_moodle_database->query_end()
* line 1684 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: call to mysqli_native_moodle_database->get_records_sql()
* line 1656 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->get_record_sql()
* line 1635 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->get_record_select()
* line 432 of /lib/classes/session/manager.php: call to moodle_database->get_record()
* line 172 of /lib/classes/session/manager.php: call to core\session\manager::initialise_user_session()
* line 144 of /lib/classes/session/manager.php: call to core\session\manager::start_session()
* line 866 of /lib/setup.php: call to core\session\manager::start()
* line 27 of /config.php: call to require_once()
* line 41 of /lib/ajax/service.php: call to require_once()´´´

